# Trying to apply pure JavaScript effects to React ant-table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am very new to React and have recently inherited a project that was created with create-react-app. The project is partially done and I want to make the columns of a particular table adjustable (the user should drag and adjust the width). The previous developers used [ant-table](https://ant.design/components/table/) to create the table, which has no such feature.

I figured I could try and do this using plain js, like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thrilleratplay/epcybL4v/

However, I cannot make it work. I have included the js code as a  inside index.html, have also tried calling it inside the .js file of the component.

This is my component code:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'antd';
import Table from '../../components/tables/AntdTable.pg';


class SampleScreen extends Component {

  render(){
    return (


              <Table data={this.props.availableFlavors.map(this.props.generateFruitList)}
                              selectRow={this.props.selectRow}
                              headers={this.props.tableHeaders} />
    );
  }
}

SampleScreen.propTypes = {
    availableFlavors : PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    tableHeaders: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    selectRow: PropTypes.object.isRequired,    
    generateFruitList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,    
};


export default SampleScreen;
```

I am not sure if this is even possible, again, please bear with a React noob here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-resizable-column

Answer (score 0):

Check the examples at antd website on how to create tables.

[Resizable column](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-resizable-column)